# how to make code clean using generic in kotlin?

Tags: android

I want to make this code clean. So I tried using generic changing the code like below.

```
  private fun initFragment( T :Fragment){
        when(current){
            is HomeFragment->{
                var fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container) as  T
                fragmentManager.init()
            }
            is SecondFragment->{
                var fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container) as  T
                fragmentManager.init()
            }
        }
    }
```

And

```
var fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)

    private fun initFragment( current :Fragment){
        when(current){
            is HomeFragment->{
                (fragmentManager as  HomeFragment).init()
            }
            is SecondFragment->{
                (fragmentManager as  SecondFragment).init()
            }
        }
    }
```

but both occured error. first error is red line grammarly, second occured null error. So I changed having boiler code. how can I make it clear?

```
    private fun initFragment( current :Fragment){
        when(current){
            is HomeFragment->{
                var fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container) as  HomeFragment
                fragmentManager.init()
            }
            is SecondFragment->{
                var fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container) as  SecondFragment
                fragmentManager.init()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to use generics in that case just create some kind of BaseFragment which will have abstract function init. now make your fragment classes extend your BaseFragment class and implement init way you want. now back to your function "initFragment" just chake if found fragment is type of BaseFragment if it is call init function if it's not do whatever you want maybe throw an exeption or not do anything at all